# 301 redirect in .htaccess mystery

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm building a website in WordPress and my client has decided she wants to change the page name AND alias after launch

old: http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/speech-doctor

new: http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor

Google already knows about the old URL so we need to write a 301 Redirect in the .htaccess file.

I tried a couple of things, but to no avail, so can anyone tell me what is wrong with the .htaccess file below (I copied the whole content of the file):

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# hieronder van niet-www naar www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
# hieronder van http naar https
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/speech-doctor/ http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/speech-doctor-written-review-plus-2-hour-consult http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-plus-2-hour-consult
RedirectMatch 301 ^/speech-doctor-written-review-only http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-only
RedirectMatch 301 ^/speech-doctor-2-hour-consult http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/2-hour-consult
</IfModule>

# END WordPress


AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php .php5 .php4 .php3
```

Any help, much appreciated!

Thom

Answer (score 0):

I tested your suggested RedirectMatch rules and they worked perfectly on my test system. Also, you haven't actually said what isn't working. Does it redirect at all? Throw an error? Go to the original page? Continually loop? etc

Ensure your browser cache is clean? Turning redirections on/off will require a clean browser cache otherwise the browser will automagically use the redirection it already knows about.

Also, if you're doing it in wordpress then yes it is possible to do it in the .htaccess file, but it's an awful lot easier if you use a plugin

https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Hope that helps,

---

Howdy,
Had a further look into this today, your problem is probably related to mod_alias not being available on your server. @jordi above is correct

RedirectMatch is in mod_alias, where as RewriteRule is in mod_rewrite. If I disabled mod_alias the server returned a 404 for the RedirectMatch directives, along with this error in the apache log
    /.htaccess: Invalid command 'RedirectMatch', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Use Jordi Nebots response is accurate.

Comment: hi, the URLs gave me the 404 page. So that is hardly what I would like.
I cleaned the cache a number of times and also tried other browsers as well. 
I don't want to use plugins if there is a quicker way.

Comment: Howdy,
Had a further look into this today.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a leading slash on your regexp. Also, I'd make optional the trailing slash.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^speech-doctor-written-review-plus-2-hour-consult/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-plus-2-hour-consult
RedirectMatch 301 ^speech-doctor-written-review-only/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-only
RedirectMatch 301 ^speech-doctor-2-hour-consult/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/2-hour-consult
RedirectMatch 301 ^speech-doctor/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/
```

**Edit:** I've moved your first `301`to last position to avoid collisions with the other rules if the URL is visited without trailing slash.

Please, try to move this four rules below `RewriteBase`.

```
RewriteBase /
# Move 301 redirects here #
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
```

**To answer your comment:** I've moved down the first rule because if (e.g.) you visit the URL:

> http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/speech-doctor-2-hour-consult

This URL matches both `^speech-doctor-2-hour-consult/?` and `^speech-doctor/?` rules. So, if `RedirectMatch 301 ^speech-doctor/?` is your first redirection rule what will happen is that http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/speech-doctor-2-hour-consult will be redirected to http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/ as rules are processed from top to bottom.

Comment: Hi Jordi, thanx for the effort, but this doesn't work. All links go to the 404 page. Secondly: I don't understand why you would want to move the speech-doctor 301 to the bottom, as the others use dashes not slashes for the rest of the URL, so they are seen as totally different URLs. Lastly: I was thinking: is there perhaps something else in the .htaccess file that prevents the rules from working?

Comment: Hi Jordi, Thanx for your explanation. You're right about the order of the redirects. Still, the redirects still don't work. Is there perhaps something else in the .htaccess file that prevents the rules from working? Or would there be another reason why it doesn't work?

Comment: Pattern of redirectmatch directive is not relative to the current dir, it must starts with full path and a leading slash.

Comment: @starkeen could you write that in plain English, so I can understand?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, have you tried using `RewriteRule` to do your redirections? It's what I usually do...

```
RewriteRule ^speech-doctor-written-review-plus-2-hour-consult/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-plus-2-hour-consult [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^speech-doctor-written-review-only/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/written-review-only [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^speech-doctor-2-hour-consult/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/2-hour-consult [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^speech-doctor/? http://www.successfulspeakernow.com/executive-speech-doctor/ [R=301,L]
```

Also, I assume you've checked you really have `mod_rewrite` enabled on Apache and your `.htaccess` file is being processed, right?

Comment: Let me get this straight: For RewriteRule I need mod_rewrite, don't I? And for Redirect I don't need mod_rewrite, do I? As I wrote before, in my question I had copied the whole .htaccess file and I asked above, is there something missing from my .htaccess file? I'm not an .htaccess specialist, so please, bear with me. ...

Comment: For `RewriteRule` you need `mod_rewrite`. For `RedirectMatch` you need `mod_alias`. **But** all your code is inside a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block, so if you **don't** have `mod_rewrite` enabled, nothing on your `.htaccess` will be processed.